# Analyze an RC circuit using either nodal or mesh analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, nodal-analysis, mesh-analysis

How can I analyze the circuit shown in the diagram below using either nodal analysis or mesh analysis? I attempted solving the problem using mesh but ended up with the wrong answer.

[image]

[image]

To obtain the correct answer, I must obtain the differential equation: `dv/dt + 0.25v = 0` and not `dv/dt + 0.75v = 0` as shown in the working. Can anyone tell me what it is I am doing wrong?

Comment: Mesh 2: \$6(i_0-i_1)\$-->\$6(i_1-i_0)\$. Capacitor defining relation: \$i_o=-Cdv/dt\$

Answer (score 0):

Well, we have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1XLK4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using KCL, we can see that:

$$0=\text{I}_1\left(t\right)+\text{I}_2\left(t\right)+\text{I}_3\left(t\right)\tag1$$

And for the voltages we can see:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\text{I}_1\left(t\right)&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1\left(t\right)-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2\left(t\right)&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1\left(t\right)-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3\left(t\right)&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1\left(t\right)-\text{V}_2\left(t\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}\\
\\
\text{I}_3\left(t\right)&=\left(\text{V}_2'\left(t\right)-0\right)\text{C}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}
\tag2
$$

Combinging, gives:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{alignat*}{1}
0&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1\left(t\right)-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1\left(t\right)-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1\left(t\right)-\text{V}_2\left(t\right)}{\displaystyle\text{R}_3}\\
\\
0&=\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1\left(t\right)-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_1}+\frac{\displaystyle\text{V}_1\left(t\right)-0}{\displaystyle\text{R}_2}+\left(\text{V}_2'\left(t\right)-0\right)\text{C}
\end{alignat*}
\end{cases}
\tag3
$$

Which is really easy to solve :).